# Viewing txt files on browser leads to App crash Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/

Tags: android

I am trying to open log.txt via file provider on browser,  however the app crashes with IllegalArgumentException,

below I have copied snippets I'm using. let me know if you require more details.

```
        String mReportsONSD =  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
            + File.separator
            + "reports"
            + File.separator;
        String Logfile = "logd.txt";

        File newFile = new File(mReportsONSD+Logfile);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null);
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName.unflattenFromString("com.android.chrome/com.google.android.apps.chrome.Main"));

             Uri logURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, getPackageName(), newFile);

        intent.setData(logURI );

        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

        startActivity(intent);
```

paths.xml to access file from external storage.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

  <external-files
      name="external_files"
      path="/" />
</paths>
```

Here is Logcat

```
  Process: com.stylingandroid.fileprovider, PID: 12241
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/reports/logd.txt
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:711)
    at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:400)
    at com.stylingandroid.fileprovider.MainActivity.startPlayer(MainActivity.java:136)
    at com.stylingandroid.fileprovider.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:68)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6261)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:11157)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:23748)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing named `external-files` in [the `FileProvider` metadata spec](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider?hl=en). Change it to `external-path`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>

  <external-path
      name="external_files"
      path="/" />
</paths>
```

Also:

- You can replace `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null);` with `new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);`
- `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` [is deprecated in Android Q and will be obsolete by next year](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/06/07/death-external-storage-end-saga.html), so I **strongly** recommend that you store your content somewhere else (e.g., the directory identified through `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`)

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it is not a crash but I get this url `content://com.stylingandroid.fileprovider/external_files/reports/logd.txt`  with error `Err:FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: I tried to set the permissions `grantUriPermission("com.android.chrome", logURI/*/storage/emulated/0/reports/logd.txt*/ , Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
` still same error, am I missing something?

Comment: @user755: Perhaps you do not have a file there. Also, you are attempting to hack into Chrome with `setComponent()`, and there is no requirement for Chrome to support your request.

Comment: I think one has to call `setComponent()` to launch other apps via intent with `packagename` and `acitvityname`.

Comment: @user755: That class is not part of the public API of that app. Google can rename that class whenever it wants, and your code will crash outright. If you are calling `setComponent()` and identifying some class that is not your own, you are hacking into the other app. Plus, Chrome does not have to know what to do with a `content` `Uri`, which I suspect is the more immediate source of your problem.

Comment: I'm confused now, how would the intent would know what app to launch with out invoking `setcompoent()` ? I followed your suggestion provided using `getExternalFilesDir()` I can read the log files however the browser fails to  open other file types such as html

Comment: @user755: "how would the intent would know what app to launch with out invoking setcompoent() ?" -- an implicit `Intent` (one without a component) is handled perfectly well by Android. Android looks to see which activities support the `Intent` structure (`ACTION_VIEW`, `content:` `Uri`, MIME type, etc.). See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/sending). This is also covered in many Android app development books and courses.